# Facebook registration issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am showing the facebook registration iframe in thick box (Iframe inside iframe).

(If user is not logged in, button will be shown to login or else registration form will be shown directly.)

Crom is caching data. Because of that after login to facebook it shows error like "invalid client_id" (It doesn't shows me registration form). If I reload the parent iframe ie. thickbox window registration form shows fine.

I want to reload the thickbox iframe after login to facebook. I can get this control some how?. Is there any JS code available for this ?

Here is my code

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="reg-cont">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId   : '<?php echo $this->facebookAppId; ?>',
                    status  : true,
                    cookie  : true,
                    xfbml   : true
                });
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.status == "connected") {
                        window.location = "/facebook-login?facebook_uid=" + response.session.uid;
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
        <fb:registration
            fields="[
                             {'name':'name'},
                             {'name':'email'},
                             {'name':'church', 'description':'Home Church',  'type':'select',  'options':<?php echo str_replace('"', "'", $this->church); ?>, 'default':'none'},
                             {'name':'host',   'description':'Check this box if you are hosting your small group', 'type':'checkbox'}
                   ]"
            redirect-uri="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/User/index/create-facebook-account"
            fb_only="true"
            width="530">
        </fb:registration>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload a targeted iframe on login.  You will need to set the link, and frame name below

> ```
>     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
>        top.frames['YourFrameName'].location.href = 'http://example.com/';
>     });
> ```

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId   : '<?php echo $this->facebookAppId; ?>',
                status  : true,
                cookie  : true,
                xfbml   : true
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    window.location = "/facebook-login?facebook_uid=" + response.session.uid;
                }
            });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    top.frames['YourFrameName'].location.href = 'http://example.com/';
    });
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: This will redirect the page if user is logged in to facebook . I need to show the registration block after/if user logged in .